# Get some information from exception caught with catch(...)?

Tags: c++, exception

I have a try catch clause where the outermost `catch(...)` never happened until now. After some changes, somewhere an exception which I don't handle with the other cases is thrown. Is there a way to get at least some information about the exception even though I catch it with `(...)`?

```
catch (const cone::BeginnersLibException& ex) 
{
    // handle the exception
}
catch (const std::exception& ex) 
{
    // handle std exception
} 
catch (...) 
{
    log("Unknown exception caught.");
    // How can I get more information about this exception?
}
```

---

Edit: here a code snippet that works for me:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>

// more code here 
} catch (...) {
    std::string exName(abi::__cxa_current_exception_type()->name());
    std::cout<<"unknown exception: "<< exName <<std::endl;
    throw;
}
```

Comment: If an exception derives from `std::exception`, you can call `catch (const std::exception &exc)` and then use `exc.what()`

Comment: @Mints97: sure, but that's not the OP's situation.

Comment: It was missing a code snippet

Comment: @Niall somehow it was not shown before. thanks for the edit!

Comment: Syntax aside, the *semantic* point is "never catch an exception you don't know how to handle" (because you deny higher-level code to catch it *and handle it correctly*. The idea is that you `catch ( ... )` to do some internal record keeping (like that `log()` in your code), then re-`throw` the exception. If you don't even know the *type* of the exception, you obviously don't know how to handle it correctly. In this case, re-throwing (passing it on) and risking the eventual `terminate()` doesn't look like that bad a response...

Comment: demangling the result will help :

Comment: int status = 0;
    auto name = abi::__cxa_current_exception_type()->name();
    auto demangledName = abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status);
        std::cout<<"unknown exception: "<< demangledName <<std::endl;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this using gdb or another debugger.  Tell the debugger to stop when any exception is throw (in gdb the command is hilariously `catch throw`).  Then you will see not only the type of the exception, but where exactly it is coming from.

Another idea is to comment out the `catch (...)` and let your runtime terminate your application and hopefully tell you more about the exception.

Once you figure out what the exception is, you should try to replace or augment it with something that does derive from `std::exception`.  Having to `catch (...)` at all is not great.

If you use GCC or Clang you can also try `__cxa_current_exception_type()->name()` to get the name of the current exception type.

Comment: I had to include cxxabi.h

Comment: +1 for `__cxa_current_exception_type()->name()`.  Since there is no language support for inspecting the exception, vendor- and platform-specific extensions are a pragmatic way to go.

Comment: Please repost this answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055299/is-there-any-way-to-get-some-information-at-least-for-catch ; this is the same question as that, but your answer offers options that are not visible there.

Comment: @zwol: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28553795/4323

Comment: demangling the result will help

Comment: int status = 0;
    auto name = abi::__cxa_current_exception_type()->name();
    auto demangledName = abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status);
        std::cout<<"unknown exception: "<< demangledName <<std::endl;

Comment: This is not likely to be useful. Clang is giving me a std::exception* from this, for something that is clearly not.  The newer c++11 std::current_exception() or std::exception_ptr can also be used, but they only give you a shared void* for the exception.  Nothing but the right type will give you the actual data.

Answer (score 5):

As a variant on John Zwinck's suggestion to comment out the `catch(...)` block to let the run-time terminate the application and hopefully provide some more info, you could

```
catch (...) 
{
  log("Unknown exception caught in [sensible info here]; will rethrow it");
  throw;
}
```

then you will at least know where in your program the error occured (if there are several possibilities).

Answer (score 2):

One possibility too, on Windows at least, is to write a minidump using MiniDumpWriteDump to get the exception plus stack traces, memory and lots of useful debugging info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a debugger and enable break on throw, assuming your exceptions really are exceptional this is a good way to know where its coming from.

Also a word of warning should you ever use catch(...) on windows. Under certain build options this will catch SEH exceptions, these are the kinds of things you should never attempt handle such as reading or writing memory out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

The only way in code (i.e. not using a debugger) to get information from an exception in a `catch(...)` block is to rethrow the exception, and catch it with specific clauses.

For example.

```
try
{
    // code that might throw something
}
catch (...)
{
    try_to_interpret_exception();
}

void try_to_interpret_exception()   // we assume an exception is active
{
    try
    {
         throw;    // rethrow the exception.  Calls terminate() if no exception active
    }
    catch (std::exception &)
    {
         // handle all exception types derived from std::exception
         //    this covers all exceptions that might be thrown by
         //    the standard C++ library
    }
    catch (specific_exception &e1)
    {
        //  handle all exception types derived from specific_exception
    }
    catch (another_specific_exception &e2)
    {
         // etc
    }
}
```

The catch (so to speak) of this approach is that it requires the programmer to have some knowledge of what the exception might be (e.g. from documentation of a third party library).
|

Comment: The problem is that the exception is coming from one of the libs and I don't know what to catch.

Comment: The only real solution then is to examine the documentation (or source code if you have it) for the libraries.   Eliminate one library at a time from your program until you find the offending library, if necessary.   Really, though, this situation would have been best avoided (e.g. by evaluating a library thoroughly before incorporating it into a production program).   Not documenting thrown exceptions is really poor form by the library vendor.

Comment: Minor nitpic: You want to go from the most specific exception type to the generic one, not the other way 'round. Some exception hierarchies derive from `std::exception`, or `std::runtime_error` (as that is where `.what()` comes into play). If you catch that first, you might catch more than you indended to.

Comment: Yes, you are right. At least it is not productive yet :)