# How to determine at runtime the type of exception pointed to by an exception_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, typeinfo

In C++11 and later, an `exception_ptr`  to the the current exception can be retrieved using `current_exception()`. Is it possible at runtime to determine the type of the exception being pointed to?

More precisely, how to get the a reference to a `type_info` of the exception pointed to by an `exception_ptr`? I know it is possible to `catch` based on the type, but then the programmer would need to write `catch` blocks for all possible the types of exceptions, which is not a solution for this problem.

```
try {
    userProvidedRuntimePlugin.executeAction(); // May throw anything
} catch (...) {
    auto e = std::current_exception();
    std::type_info & info = /* ??? */;
    std::cerr << "Exception of type " << info.name() << " thrown." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: No, type information is not available directly from the exception pointer. What's the real use case, though? You can always rethrow and catch.

Comment: @KerrekSB I can only catch by type if I know the type of the exception, or the type of a base class of the exception, which not always the case. I'm sorry I can not share more information about the real use case for legal reasons.

Comment: "Real" doesn't mean "what you are actually working on". It can perfectly well refer to an artificially constructed scenario that contains the same *design element* as your real project. You don't even have to point out what that element is. "Real" just means that you shouldn't just give us a single line and say that it doesn't do what you want. There are lots of particular things that you cannot do in C++, but that's not interesting in itself. The question is whether there's something that you might actually want that cannot be done because of it.

Comment: If all your exceptions inherits from `std::exception` you can simply catch a `std::exception&` and use `typeid` on it.

Comment: @KerrekSB I understand, but if the artificially constructed scenario in my question is not good enough for you, feel free to ignore my question. I don't want to go into an in-depth discussion about use cases, which I think misses the purpose for this inquiry. This is a simple question about a simple thing, demanding a simple answer. I humbly ask you to please resist the temptation to "fix" what you assume to be my big picture in this matter :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>

using namespace __cxxabiv1;

std::string util_demangle(std::string to_demangle)
{
    int status = 0;
    char * buff = __cxxabiv1::__cxa_demangle(to_demangle.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &status);
    if (!buff) return to_demangle;
    std::string demangled = buff;
    std::free(buff);
    return demangled;
}

try
{
   /* .... */
}
catch(...)
{
   std::cout <<"exception type: '" << util_demangle(abi::__cxa_current_exception_type()->name()) << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer actually lead me to also find some duplicates of my question on SO. For example, my question also seems to be [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28538250/3919155). Welcome to Stack Overflow! :-)

Comment: `__cxa_demangle` may return 0 and then `std::string demangled = buff` crashes your application.

Comment: "crashes your application" -  not necessarily : if buff == 0 then it throw std::logic_error.

Comment: @LeszekKosinkiewicz exception on null pointer is GCC extension, but for code using `<cxxabi.h>` its ok

Answer (score 0):

No, sadly enough you will not be able to detect the type of exception.
your `auto e` variable will simply be of type `std::exception_ptr e`

If you want to behave differently on a specific type of exception what you should do is simply catch this exception at first. Example:

```
try{
    userProvidedRuntimePlugin.executeAction(); // May throw anything
} catch (std::exception e) {
    //handle std::exception
} catch (your::exception e2) {
    //handle your::exception
}catch (...) {
    std::exception_ptr e = std::current_exception();
    cout << "unknown exception" << endl;
    std::rethrow_exception(e); // for example
}
```

if you do not know what to do with the unexpected exception at this level one option is to rethrow it using `std::rethrow_exception(e);`